# When an algorithm says Summation this, and Integral that, what does it mean in coding terms?

Tags: algorithms, numerical-algorithms, computer-algebra

I'm a student at a college with only two units of mathematics and I don't know if I'm asking in the right place so please bear with me.

I'm currently reading GPU Gems by nvidia and I have a question. It uses Sigma, as in summation, and integral a lot, but when look at the implementation of some of these algorithms, for example, Perlin noise, I can't find any sort of "summation" i.e.:

```
sum = 0
for i in range(x):
    sum += f(i)
```

They just convert the Sigma's formula to code. As for integral, I was never very good at them so I have a very weak foundation in them --- Therefore I can't even close to imagine how to convert an integral from an algorithm to code. I know integrals are two things: the area beneath the curve, and the reverse of the derivative --- But how can you derive an algorithm?

For example, this is from the Worely noise algorithm. How do you translate it to code, like Python, or anything?

[image: Worely noise]

I'm not asking for code, just explanation. And I hope this is the right place. Thank you.

Comment: This like asking ask "code $x^2 + 3x = 0$". I'm not sure what that means. I suspect that some context is missing.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus You've touched on exactly what I want. Just as x^2+3x = 0 -> x * x* + 3 * x, I want to know how to deal with Summation and Integrals in algorithm -> Summation and Integrals in code. If you think there's a book that can help me, please don't hesitate to introduce it. There are many books on the subject of algorithms, and my college doesn't have algorithms as a separate topic. Thank you.

Comment: My point was that your program never contains anything that corresponds to "$x^2 + 3x = 0$". It could possibly contain something like "let $x$ be a solution of $x^2 + 3x = 0$". This is why I'm not sure how to related your clip to an algorithm. As it stands, it's just a random equation.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I understand what you mean. I got my answer, and the answer is that I should stop looking for short solutions and read a book on computer algebra. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking at a rather mathematical sketch of an algorithm. There are two general roads to implement non-trivial mathematical expressions such as series, integrals, and differential equations.

1. If you want exact, potentially symbolic results you have to simplify "complex" expressions into closed forms on paper, and/or employ *computer algebra*.
2. If you are satisfied with numerical, potentially approximate solutions, you want to employ *numerical algorithms*, including error estimations.

Comment: I don't have good book recommendations on either; both are full-fledged fields of active research with decades of history. Specific questions are ontopic here, but the numerical end of things is probably better served over on [scicomp.SE]. The mathematical parts of both avenues can certainly be asked on [math.SE] as well. There is also [mathematica.SE] if you decide to use Mathematica, a good but proprietary and expensive computer algebra system.

Comment: As I said in the main topic, computer algebra is what I want, because GPU want exact results. Thanks.